# Second Monitor Not Detected!

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, monitor

I have a Dell M3800 and recently purchased a Dell S2715H and connected it to the laptop through the HDMI cable. For whatever reason, the monitor is not detected by ubuntu.

My older dell monitor works with no issue on the same HDMI port (through a DVI to HDMI converter). The new monitor does not have a driver for linux but I assumed a driver is not needed.

Not even sure how to debug this. What could be possibly wrong here?

Comment: You didn't mention if your old monitor was connect via HDMI as well. Or was it VGA? DisplayPort?

Comment: Just updated the text

Comment: Sorry. I really should have asked for all this in my last comment. But what version of the nvidia driver are you using? What version of Ubuntu? Are you using Bumblebee or Prime for GPU switching? Does your monitor have DVI input, and if so, can you try connecting via your old cable (HDMI -> DVI)? Sometimes monitors give out a different EDID on DVI, so you might be able to connect that way to your new monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the monitor attached PRIOR to booting as Ubuntu does not recognize an HDMI monitor while the system is running.  Other monitor types work, but not HDMI. This omission may be resolved in a later kernel.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I have done this already and still does not work